# Responsive table column widths in pixels

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have an html table (width 100%) in which each column has a specified width e.g. style="width: 240px". I cannot convert these widths to %. Is there a clever/efficient way to resize the columns (make them responsive) when the table size changes?

Comment: There is no effective way to do it without percentages, unless you want the table to do "jump"-steps, where it will reduce 100px at a time or something. The best way is probably using max-width, min-width and a percentage. Not sure if that fits your need though.

Comment: check out this->  http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries to achieve this. Like this.

```
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
        width: 30%; /* mobile device with have 70% reduction of width */
    }

}
```

Or you can directly use css like following to set any width or style.

```
table {
 width:100%;
}
```

You can also define a class ( lets say `mobile_not_show`) for `tr` ,that does not require to be visible in mobile . Then in above `media` query just set `.mobile_not_show {display:none;}`.So this will make those specific `tr` hidden in mobile only.
SOURCE - http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: A good thought but media queries won't help me. In my case, the grid table resizes when a container div (not necessarily the parent div) receives a "change size" event, which changes width of the container div.

Comment: @user1601810 , updated code, i.e. you can directly use `CSS` like shown above to make required change, without touching inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Use % for the first row

```
table th {
  width: 25%;
}
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Jill</td>
    <th>Smith</td> 
    <th>50</td>
    <th>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```